# css sprite Img load time which is faster?

Tags: css, sprite

Recently I have been switching my site over to css sprites to enhance performance. I used to have five 16 x 16px imgs for a dll,  I now have a css sprite which is 220x140px made up of those 5 images plus text.  Is it really faster to load this larger image?

Comment: size does not matter as much as the number of requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe in real live sprites are always the best solution. I just don't understand how you get from 5x 16px by 16px to a single file of 220px by 140px. If you use minimal space, you should be able to do it with a single image of 16px by 80px. Size does offcourse matter. Putting your text in an image is not a good idea imo. Sending the text as plain text in your html is much faster, plus it ads to readability for people that use screenreaders and is much better for SEO. I only put text in images if it uses some special font or styling I can't reproduce with css.

Comment: That is very true its just the way I had implemented it for the time being I also have the same image just with a different color background which is shown when hovered

Comment: One more word of advice, definitly put your hover image in the same sprite as the default ones. This makes sure they are already loaded when the hover occurs en prevents the flicker effect you sometimes get on slow connetctions. And its yet another request saved.

Comment: Thats the way I have it looks like im gonna cut the text out and just do it in css!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends"

If you load one image from the sprite image it is slower, because of the larger filesize.

But if you would start a second request for a second image, the sprite becomes faster.

Answer (score 0):

Truthfully, it depends on how many times you have to load. In smaller amounts it is slower but in larger amounts it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

When sprites are built carefully (without wasting a lot of space) and used everywhere in the site **yes**! Especially on mobile devices where latencies and time between requests can be quite large.